# Ruby gems bundle install failure

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am installing Diaspora (open source social networking) in Ubuntu 16.04 using [these directions](https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Ubuntu/Xenial).  Installation instructions call for using Ruby Version Manager to install Ruby and then using Bundler to add some required gems.  Ruby installs, then the command to use the bundler

```
:~/diaspora$ bin/bundle install --full-index
```

makes some progress and then fails at this step:

```
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.4
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory:/home/ubuntu/diaspora/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180215-26943-187isn6.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/ubuntu/diaspora/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/ubuntu/diaspora/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
Makefile:209: recipe for target 'unf.o' failed
make: *** [unf.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/diaspora/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/diaspora/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  asset_sync was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
     unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
        unf_ext
```

I updated to gcc-7 and g++-7, and appear to be using them:

```
:~/diaspora$ update-alternatives --display gcc
gcc - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/gcc-7
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gcc-7
  link gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc-7 - priority 10
:~/diaspora$ update-alternatives --display g++
g++ - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/g++-7
  link currently points to /usr/bin/g++-7
  link g++ is /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++-7 - priority 10
```

I also successfully installed unf_ext without Bundler using

```
:~/diaspora$ gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4'
```

and it is there:

```
:~/diaspora$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bundler (default: 1.16.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.3.2, 1.2.7)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (default: 2.0.2)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.0.3)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
rake (12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (2.7.5, 2.6.14)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.2.3)
unf_ext (0.0.7.5, 0.0.7.4, 0.0.7.2)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
```

... but the same error persists.

Looking to understand the source of the error and how to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your box is running out of memory during the installation:

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
```

It is killing the install.  You should increase your system's memory.

Comment: Adding a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) is probably the easiest way to solve this for the purposes of the install